# How to get all issues which I moved to "Resolved"

Tags: filter, jira

Is it possible to create a filter JIRA to get all issues, which I set to Status "Resolved" in the last 7 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just resolved it. Here is the filter:

```
resolved >= -7d AND status was resolved by currentuser()
```

This query Outputs all issus which moved to "Resolved" by a specific user in the last 7 days.